# Rails and ReactJS - Re-rendering component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

So i'm still playing with a Todo application in order to learn Reactjs.
The application is quit simple, a user can add a new task and mark it as completed.

I'm using Rails on the backend using the react-rails gem and tried differents approach to handle component re-rendering when a new task is created or just updated.

Instead of fetching the data from the server at a given interval, i'm rendering a JSON with all the tasks from the backend everytime a new task is created or updated.

I was wondering if this is the most optimized approched.
So here's my Rails controller :

```html
class TasksController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :get_tasks

 def get_tasks
  @tasks = Task.where('iscompleted is null').order(created_at: :desc)
 end

 def index
  render :json => @tasks
 end

 def create
  @task = Task.create(task_params)

  render :json => @tasks
 end

 def update
  @task = Task.update(params[:id], task_params)

  render :json => @tasks
 end



 private
 def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:id, :name, :iscompleted)
 end
end
```

and here's my ReactJS component :

```js
var TodoBox = React.createClass({

 loadTasksFromServer: function() {
  $.ajax({
   url: this.props.url,
   dataType: 'json',
   cache: false,
   success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: data.tasks});
   }.bind(this)
  });
 },
 handleTaskSubmit: function(task) {
  $.ajax({
   url: this.props.url,
   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {task},
   success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: data.tasks});
   }.bind(this),
   error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
   }.bind(this)
  });  
 },
 handleTaskCompleted: function(task) {
  $.ajax({
   url: '/task/' + task.id,
   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'PATCH',
   data: {task},
   success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: data.tasks});
   }.bind(this),
   error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
   }.bind(this)
  });
  
 },
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   data: []
  };
 },
 componentDidMount: function() {
  this.loadTasksFromServer();
 },
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div className="todoBox">
   <div className="container-fluid col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <TodoForm onTaskSubmit={this.handleTaskSubmit}/>
   <TodoList onTaskCompleted={this.handleTaskCompleted} data={this.state.data}/>
   
   </div>
   
   </div>
   );
 }
});
```

This method is working very well but i'm here to learn so every comment or advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about refactoring working code are more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: So is your question about: "whether it's the right approach to just re-render with all tasks rather than determine which task has been added/removed/updated in order to call render?"
If that's the question, then it's the right approach to use ReactJS. React runs a virtual dom diff algorithm to minimize the Dom manipulation which is the expensive part

Comment: @NaturalLam thanks for your answer. So basically, if i want to re-render all tasks this is the right approah. But what would be the right approach to determine which task has been added/updated ? Is there a way not to re-render all tasks ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that filtering the results in React is more effective since it down't require to rerender all the tasks from the backend.
Therefore, i'm only rendering the new object or the updated object from rails backend as follow :

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

def index
    @tasks = Task.all
    render :json => @tasks
end

def create
    @task = Task.create(task_params)

    render :json => @task
end

def update
    @task = Task.update(params[:id], task_params)

    render :json => @task
end



private
def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:id, :name, :iscompleted)
end
```

And therefore the React component looks like this :

```
var TodoBox = React.createClass({

loadTasksFromServer: function() {
    var rawData = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: data.tasks});
        }.bind(this)
    });
},


handleTaskSubmit: function(task) {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {task},
        success: function(data) {
            this.state.data.push(data.task);
            this.setState({data: this.state.data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });     
},
handleTaskCompleted: function(task) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/task/' + task.id,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'PATCH',
        data: {task},
        success: function(data) {
            task.iscompleted = data.task.iscompleted;
            this.setState({data: this.state.data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });

},
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        data: []
    };
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadTasksFromServer();
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="todoBox">
        <div className="container-fluid col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <TodoForm onTaskSubmit={this.handleTaskSubmit}/>
        <TodoList onTaskCompleted={this.handleTaskCompleted} data={this.state.data}/>

        </div>

        </div>
        );
}
```

});

Then i'm filtering the results in the TodoList component before displaying them.